# How to label & caption a circuitikz environment

Tags: captions, labels, circuitikz

I have been looking for a way to label and caption my `circuitikz` environment but I cannot seem to figure it out.
Any help?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx, circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz} 
        \draw (0,0) to [short, *-, l=$\mathrm{n^1_e}$(i)] (1,0)
        to [short] (1,-0.4)
        to [short] (0.3,-0.4)
        to [R, l_=$\mathrm{G_{ii}/2}$] (0.3,-2)
        to [short] (1.7,-2)
        to [C, l_=$\mathrm{C_{ii}/2}$] (1.7,-0.4)
        to [short] (1,-0.4);
        \draw (1,-2) node[ground]{} (1,-0.4);
        \draw (1,0) 
        to [R, l=$\mathrm{R_{ii}}$(i)] (3,0)
        to [short] (3.3,0)
        to [L, l=$\mathrm{L_{ii}}$(i)] (4.3,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer by myself.
I placed my `circuitikz` within a `figure` environment :)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx, circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{circuitikz} 
    \draw (0,0) to [short, *-, l=$\mathrm{n^1_e}$(i)] (1,0)
    to [short] (1,-0.4)
    to [short] (0.3,-0.4)
    to [R, l_=$\mathrm{G_{ii}/2}$] (0.3,-2)
    to [short] (1.7,-2)
    to [C, l_=$\mathrm{C_{ii}/2}$] (1.7,-0.4)
    to [short] (1,-0.4);
    \draw (1,-2) node[ground]{} (1,-0.4);
    \draw (1,0) 
    to [R, l=$\mathrm{R_{ii}}$(i)] (3,0)
    to [short] (3.3,0)
    to [L, l=$\mathrm{L_{ii}}$(i)] (4.3,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{I did it by myself!!!}
\label{I solved my own problem, lol}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```